# How can I handle a vuex dispatch response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, aws-amplify

I'm raising the white flag and asking for suggestions even though I feel the answer is probably right in front of my face.

I have a login form that I am submitting to an api (AWS) and acting on the result. The issue I am having is once the `handleSubmit` method is called, I am immediately getting into the `console.log` statement... which to no surprise returns `dispatch result:  undefined`

I realize this is likely not a direct function of vue.js, but how I have the javascript set executing.

Here is my login component:

```
// SignInForm.vue

handleSubmit() {
    try {
        const {username, password} = this.form;

        this.$store.dispatch('user/authenticate', this.form).then(res => {
            console.log('dispatch result: ', res);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: SignInForm.handleSubmit", error);
    }
},
...
```

Here is what my store is doing. I'm sending it to a `UserService` I've created. Everything is working great. I am getting the correct response(s) and can log everything out I need. The `UserService` is making an axios request (AWS Amplify) and returning the response.

```
// user.js (vuex store)

authenticate({state, commit, dispatch}, credentials) {
    dispatch('toggleLoadingStatus', true);

    UserService.authenticate(credentials)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch('toggleLoadingStatus', false);

            if (response.code) {
                dispatch("setAuthErrors", response.message);
                dispatch('toggleAuthenticated', false);
                dispatch('setUser', undefined);

                // send error message back to login component
            } else {
                dispatch('toggleAuthenticated', true);
                dispatch('setUser', response);

                AmplifyEventBus.$emit("authState", "authenticated");

                // Need to move this back to the component somehow
                //     this.$router.push({
                //         name: 'dashboard',
                //     });
            }

            return response;
        });
},
...
```

Where I'm getting stuck at is, if I have error(s) I can set the errors in the state, but I'm not sure how to access them in the other component. I've tried setting the `data` property to a computed method that looks at the store, but I get errors.

I'm also struggling to use vue-router if I'm successfully authenticated. From what I've read I really don't want to be doing that in the state anyway -- so that means I need to return the success response back to the `SignInForm` component so I can use vue-router to redirect the user to the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. Just took me ~6 hours, posting to SO and then re-evaluating everything (again) to figure it out. It was in fact, somewhat of a silly mistake. But to help anyone else here's what I was doing wrong...

```
// SignInForm.vue

async handleSubmit() {
    try {
        await this.$store.dispatch("user/authenticate", this.form)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('SignInForm.handleSubmit response: ', response);  // works

            if (response.code) {
                this.errors.auth.username = this.$store.getters['user/errors'];
            } else {
                this.$router.push({
                    name: 'dashboard',
                });
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('big problems: ', error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: SignInForm.handleSubmit", error);
    }
},
...
```

Here's my first mistake: I was calling from an `async` method to another method - but not telling that method to be `async` so the call(er) method response was executing right away. Here's the updated vuex store:

```
 // user.js (vuex store)

 async authenticate({state, commit, dispatch}, credentials) { // now async
    dispatch('toggleLoadingStatus', true);

    return await UserService.authenticate(credentials)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('UserService.authenticate response: ', response);  // CognitoUser or code

            dispatch('toggleLoadingStatus', false);

            if (response.code) {
                dispatch("setAuthErrors", response.message);
                dispatch('toggleAuthenticated', false);
                dispatch('setUser', undefined);
            } else {
                dispatch('toggleAuthenticated', true);
                dispatch('setUser', response);

                AmplifyEventBus.$emit("authState", "authenticated");
            }

            return response;
        });
},
...
```

My second error was that I wasn't returning the result of the method at all from the vuex store.

Old way:

```
UserService.authenticate(credentials)
```

Better way:

```
return await UserService.authenticate(credentials)
```

Hope this saves someone a few hours. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

This works for Vue3:

```
export default {
    name: 'Login',
    methods: {
        loginUser: function () {
            authenticationStore.dispatch("loginUser", {
                email: 'peter@example.com',
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log('Do something')
                }
            });
        },
    },
}
```

In the store you can simply pass back the http response which is a promise.

```
const authenticationStore = createStore({
    actions: {
        loginUser({commit}, {email}) {
            const data = {
                email: email
            };

            return axios.post(`/authentication/login/`, data)
                .then(response => {
                    toastr.success('Success')
                    return response
                })
        },

    }
})
```